# Source not found error while performing data driven testing in selenium using java in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Hi,

```
public static  String[][] excelRead() throws Exception{
        FileInputStream fis=null;   
        HSSFWorkbook wb=null;
        File excel=new File("C:\\MyEclipseWorkspace\\SeleniumWD\\Commodity1.xlsx");     
        fis=new FileInputStream(excel);     
        wb=new HSSFWorkbook(fis);       
        HSSFSheet ws=wb.getSheet("com");        
        int rowCount=ws.getLastRowNum()+1;
        int colCount=ws.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();     
        String[][] data=new String[rowCount][colCount];     
        for(int i=0;i<rowCount;i++){
            HSSFRow row=ws.getRow(i);
            for(int j=0;j<colCount;j++){
                HSSFCell cell=row.getCell(j);
                String value= cellToString(cell);
                data[i][j]=value;
                System.out.println("Value is " +value);
         } 
       }
        return data;
    }
```

I am working with selenium Eclipse and have to perform data driven testing. I wrote a code below to import an excel sheet data.
The below methods does so, 
Now since i am executing this method it shows **Source not found**. I am not able to find the solution to this. I have already include poi-3.9.jar file in the library. 
Please assists me regarding this.
Thanks in advance,